# Does malloc and new know about each other?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Assume I have 10 kB heap and mix C and C++ code like that.

```
char* block1 = malloc(5*1024); //allocate 5
char* block2 = new[](4*1024); // allocate 4
```

Is there C heap and C++ heap or just a single heap common for both? So that "new" knows that the first 5 kb of heap are already allocated?

Comment: This really depends on your implementation.  `new` often calls `malloc`, but you'd have to check the source code to know.

Comment: It's not "new" knows about "malloc" nor the opposite, it's the OS knows about allocations made in the context of current process, regardless of what command was used for that.

Comment: If you are really asking, *"Is it safe to use `new` and `malloc` in the same program?"*, then the answer is **yes**.

Comment: @abelenky But not to mix delete and free() on the same pointer

Comment: From a process organization point of view, the OS provides a single "service" to a process to request dynamic memory allocation. From a process software point of view, the allocation API could use separate data structures to track their allocations, and need not be aware of the other API's structures.

Comment: Darwin sorts this out.  Practically any non-trivial C++ program takes a dependency on a C library.  The C++ library author ensures his library will compete by using malloc() in his new implementation.

Comment: On my platform, the `malloc` heap is independent from the `new` heap and the `new[]` heap.  They play nice together.  You can't mix-and-match those willy-nilly with `free`, `delete`, and `delete[]` though... that goes bad fast.

Answer (score 8):

There may or may not be separate C and C++ heaps. You can't write a conforming C++ program that can tell the difference, so it's entirely up to the implementation.

The standard describes the first step in the default behavior of `operator new` like this:

> Executes a loop: Within the loop, the function first attempts to
>   allocate the requested storage. Whether the attempt involves a call to
>   the C standard library functions malloc or aligned_alloc is
>   unspecified. [new.delete.single]/4.1.

And for `malloc` itself, the standard says: "[`aligned_alloc`, `calloc`, `malloc`, and `realloc`] do not attempt to allocate storage by calling `::operator new()`" [c.malloc]/3.

So the intention is that it's okay to call `malloc` from `operator new`, but it's not required.

In practice, `operator new` calls `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

The way that memory allocation works, is that the userspace program first requests one or several *memory pages* from the operating systems by means of a *syscall* ([sbrk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) or [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on *nix).
This is usually done by the malloc-implementation (there are [several](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)) that is included in your "C-library". This malloc-implementation then manages all pages that it (successfully) requested. *This is done in userspace*.

Returning to your question: Most implementations of *::operator new* will just relay to malloc. **But** you can always use a different allocator-implementation and even mix several in your program (see: memory pools).*

This is the reason why the standard requires you to not mix malloc/free and new/delete.

*) Many malloc-implementations have problems with lots of small objects (which is pretty common in C++), this is a good reason for changing the allocator.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient implementation should rather be using system calls `brk()`/`mmap()` directly rather than going via `malloc()`.
Though looking at gnu implementation, that isn't the case. It's using `malloc()` internally.